# MS SQL Server 2012 installation error : 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install MS SQL server 2012 EXP on Windows 7 64bit while installing i am facing below error :

> The following error has occurred:
>   Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

I googled and tried few solution to uninstall windows update 
KB2918614 KB3000988 but still facing same error.

Please do suggest any valuable comments to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you restart your machine after uninstalling the update?

Comment: yes i did , i uninstall both updates then restart system

Comment: Run the installer file as administrator.

Comment: I run installer as admin too, but still failing.